# Android Studio doesn't install app with launcher, app only visible in app settings

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio doesn't install app properly. It's not visible in the apps launcher. Already tried to keep only MAIN and LAUNCHER intent filter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".App">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation_drawer" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:scheme="mainactivity" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.web.WebViewActivity"/>
</application>
```

Comment: what device are you testing ? Emulator or real device ?

Comment: on a real device, Nexus 5

Comment: Do you get any ADB errors?

Comment: No errors, neither during deployment nor during runtime. Tried it in emulator now, same issue.

Comment: Remove the `data` tag. It renders the launcher part of the intent filter useless. Declare separate intent filters for launcher and browsable. See Example filters [on this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to define intent filters seperately:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".App">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation_drawer" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:scheme="mainactivity" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.web.WebViewActivity"/>
</application>
```

[Example in android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleFilters)